# after using reset_index from a groupby & count on a DF cannot rename count column

Tags: python, pandas, count, rename, pandas-groupby

This my code below as I've carried out a groupby and count on a large dataframe

```
group3=charity.groupby(['Split', 'B4']).size()
group3=group3.reset_index()

out
       split     B4     0
  0     CRk      No    193
  1     CRuk     Yes    7
  2     LLR      No    184
  3     LLR      Yes    15
  4     MUK      No     188
  5     MUK      Yes    12
  6     MCUK     No    186
  7     MCUK     Yes    14
```

Below code does not work

```
  group3=group3.rename(columns={"0": "count1"})
  group3 #does not work
```

want to rename the new 0 column created by the count function so I can add other columns to the data frame for a chi-square test

also wondering how I can do count function on multiple columns in addition to the  B4 column above

Comment: `group3.rename(columns={0: "count1"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter name in [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
group3=charity.groupby(['Split', 'B4']).size().reset_index(name='count1')
```

Or rename scalar number `0`:

```
group3 = group3.rename(columns={0: "count1"})
```

**Sample**:

```
charity = pd.DataFrame({'B4':list('abbbbb'),
                       'Split':list('aaabbb')})

print (charity)
  B4 Split
0  a     a
1  b     a
2  b     a
3  b     b
4  b     b
5  b     b

group3=charity.groupby(['Split', 'B4']).size().reset_index(name='count1')
print (group3)
  Split B4  count1
0     a  a       1
1     a  b       2
2     b  b       3
```